# SQL Database Design with more than one data in same column

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I want to create a database table which will have multiply information. One of these information is phones. How can I create a database table that inside the phones column will contain let's say sub-columns, because a user may have more than one phone and be stored in the same row for the same ID.

Below is an image of what I mean and how I want my table to be...
[image]

**ALL THE ANSWERS ARE HELPFUL UNFORTUNATELY I CAN PICK ONLY ONE BUT ALL ANSWERED HELPED ME**

Comment: Which DBMS are using ?

Comment: Of course, normalizing your data model (as shown in all answers) is the recommended way, but some DBMSes support *arrays*, which could be used for storing this kind of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7de40/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table my_user (
    ID  int primary key,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    LastName varchar(255),
    address varchar(max)
)
create table user_phones (
     ID int primary key,
     userId int references my_user(ID),
     countrycode int,
     phone varchar(max),
     type varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO my_user(ID,FirstName,LastName,address) VALUES(1,'test','test','test');
INSERT INTO user_phones(ID,userId,countrycode,phone,type)VALUES(1,1,99,'000099900','mobile');
INSERT INTO user_phones(ID,userId,countrycode,phone,type)VALUES(2,1,99,'99900000','home');
INSERT INTO user_phones(ID,userId,countrycode,phone,type)VALUES(3,1,99,'000009999','fax');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from my_user u
left join user_phones p on u.ID=p.userId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7de40/2/0)**:

```
| ID | FirstName | LastName | address | ID | userId | countrycode |     phone |   type |
|----|-----------|----------|---------|----|--------|-------------|-----------|--------|
|  1 |      test |     test |    test |  1 |      1 |          99 | 000099900 | mobile |
|  1 |      test |     test |    test |  2 |      1 |          99 |  99900000 |   home |
|  1 |      test |     test |    test |  3 |      1 |          99 | 000009999 |    fax |
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no notion of *subcolumns* in relational databases.

If you want to store a variable number of phones per user, one solution is to create a another table to store them as *rows*. The `phones` table should have a column to store the id of the user each phone relates to, with a foreign key constraint that ensures that the value contained in that column do exist in the `users` table.

So:

```
users(id, name, address)
phones(id, user_id, phone_no)
```

**[Typical DDL (MySQL syntax)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=147229ef1bd8baf0fc848ff85aca53aa)**:

```
create table users (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address varchar(50)
);

create table phones(
     id int primary key auto_increment,
     user_id int not null,
     phone_no varchar(20) not null,
     foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You generally do not.  You create another table.  Say you have:

```
create table users (
    userId serial primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    . . .
);
```

Then you create a "junction" or "association" table:

```
create table userPhones (
     userPhoneId serial primary key,
     userId int references users(userId),
     phone varchar(32)
);
```

You don't specify the database.  I used `serial` for the primary key because it is used by Postgres and easy to type.

Answer (score 2):

That's a ER flow as has a phoneid in your case via primary key foreign key relation

```
       users(id (Pk), name, address, phoneid(fk))

       phones(userid(fk), phoneid (pk), phonenumber) 
       here userid and phoneid references users.phoneid and users.id
```